# Blender Shading Issues on Render

Tags: rendering, shaders

I have modeled a CRT Monitor low poly model. Everything goes right until render.
I modeled in low poly from scratch without subsurf, and finally shaded the model smooth and used Auto smooth with angle 70degree and smoothing my model. I not applied any normal maps for it.
It looks good in viewport but in render the edge looks weird in some angle. What can I do to clear this issue?
And another thing its works for some HDRIs and not working for others. What's the issue and things causing it?
Thank you in advance
Manikkam P
[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: You might have some flipped normals.  Try selecting the whole mesh in edit mode, then select `mesh > normals > recalculate outside` and see if that clears it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I have tried that and almost everything related to shading like Edge split, weighted normals,  custom normals, recalculate. Is the HDRIs will cause this kind of issues?

Comment: It could be topology related, then. If you look just above the top-left corner of the highlighted section (on the front of the monitor) in your 3'd image down from the top, there is a lone tri, right where that strange edge section begins. Can't be sure that's causing it, but it might contribute.

Comment: Thank you, I will look at that tris.